# Using images uploaded to Slack in message attachments

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I would like to upload a file using `slack.files.upload` (node api) without posting it directly to a channel.

Instead i would like to reference the file inside a message as attachment (`image_url`).

However, when uploading without a channel the resulting `url_private` is invalid.

When posting to a channel `url_private` is valid, but the image is automatically shown in the chat (i don't want that).

```
 await slack.files.upload({
        filename,
        file: buffer,
        channels: "sem-test"
    })
```

Works.

```
await slack.files.upload({
            filename,
            file: buffer
          })
```

does not give an error, but the resulting `url_private` points to an invalid file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use images uploaded to Slack as attachments without sharing them in a channel.

This works if you make those files public, because image links in message attachments can only use links to public URLs:

1. Upload file with [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) and retrieve the file ID
2. Make file URL public with [`files.sharedPublicURL`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL) and retrieve `permalink_public`
3. Attach image to attachment using `permalink_public` for the `image_url` property

Also, `url_private` is a valid URL, but you need to provide an authorization header in order to use it:

```
Authorization: Bearer A_VALID_TOKEN
```

See [here](https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication) for more details on authentication for Slack files.

Comment: What exactly does public in this context mean? Is it public for everybody or only for users authenticated to the private workspace?

Comment: public as in accessible for everyone on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that any files that have been uploaded without a channel will be private.

However, as a workaround you can create another channel for the sole purpose to upload files there and reference to this files from a different channel.

Comment: That is only party correct. Any file uploaded to Slack is private and can only be accessed directly with an authentication header unless its made public as I pointed out in my answer.